# Is it possible to match both tenses in this sentence

Tags: sentence-construction, past-tense

Is it possible to write

> I saw that you  have not accepted my PayPal payment yet.

Saw is past, have not is present perfect (the action begins in the past but ends in" present") and in this particular case it means I expect the person to accept the payment in the future, am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I saw that you have not accepted my PayPal payment yet.

This is acceptable. There is a slight stress between the tenses (if you "saw" it, then how do you know that they haven't accepted in the time between when you saw it and now?) But it is only slight and doesn't make the sentence hard to parse, or markedly odd.

You could avoid this stress by using past perfect: "I saw that you hadn't accepted..." or past tense: "I saw that you didn't accept..."  (This second form would be used if the payment had been actively *rejected* and not just *not accepted")

Answer (score 0):

You could also say this:

> I see you haven’t accepted my PayPal payment yet.

That's how I would put it if I were addressing the person directly about the issue.